# Invalid driver requested

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just upgraded my project from CodeIgniter 2 to CodeIgniter 3 for the driver auto-load feature. I'm trying to create a custom driver, but sadly the documentation doesn't give me the steps to do it.

My driver worked fine in CodeIgniter 3, but it doesn't in 2. I've updated all my class and file names according to [the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html).

I have the following file structure:

```
/libraries
    /Testdriver
         /drivers
             Testdriver_test.php
         Testdriver.php
```

Content of Testdriver.php:

```
class Testdriver extends CI_Driver_Library
{
     function __construct()
     {
          $this->valid_drivers = array('testdriver_test'); //Still not sure why this must be here, but the documentation doesn't explain me anything
     }

     function test()
     {
          echo "Hello world from parent driver";
     }
}
```

Content of Testdriver_test.php:

```
class Testdriver_test extends CI_Driver
{
     public function index()
     {
         echo "Hello world!";
     }
 }
```

Auto-load the driver, and calling the function in pages.php:

```
  $this->testdriver->test(); //This works, I can successfully call the method from the parent driver
  $this->testdriver->test->index(); //This doesn't work, gives me the "Invalid driver requested" error
```

Why did this work in CodeIgniter 2 and not anymore? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

All your file names and class names are Ok. The one wrong is in the $valid_drivers array. You have this:

```
$this->valid_drivers = array('testdriver_test');
```

And you should enter this:

```
$this->valid_drivers = array('test');
```